# New to android - not able to import sample project into eclipse

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Not able to import into eclipse sample from here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Here is what i tried:

- right click - NEW - OTHER -  Existing Projects into Workspace
- import - general - existing project into workspace
- NEW - project - chose "Android Sample Project"

Yet, none of these worked.

Comment: no error, just that that finish button does not appear when i do the import.

Comment: can u post the screen shot

Comment: i don't have enough points to be allowed to post screen shot, are you able to import this project into eclipse ? if so, just document your steps

Comment: upload free picture on any free hosting site and post the link

Answer (score 1):

1. Unzip
2. Right Click to project explorer
3. Import
4. Android/existing android code into workspace (you can click 'copy project to workspace')
5. Browse
6. Finish
7. Clean Project

Comment: when i click on import, option #4 does not appear

Comment: Sounds like you have not installed the android development tools in eclipse. (They are called adt).

Comment: were you able to download and import this project and run it in eclipse ?

Comment: yes, i check your url, import it, then i post answer. If you cant see you have not install android sdk and plugin of android for eclipse